# I need to parametrize a method in Python

Tags: python, overloading

I want to do the following:

```
def apply_indicator(df, indicator="rsi"):
    print("first one")

def apply_indicator(df, indicator="ichimoku"):
    print("second one")
```

so that the `indicator` keyword would parametrize the method

I tried if statement over indicator parameter which is phoney though.

Method overloading is not a solution neither. Python seems to confuse the two function.

Comment: what is best to do? I can define `rsi()` and `ichimoku` and a method `apply_indicator(indicator)` with `if indicator=="rsi": rsi()`.

Comment: What makes you think it's "phoney"? In Python it's exactly the right thing to do. You might find it insightful to look at the source code of larger python libraries, e.g., the [`to_json` function in pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5115f0964a47c116e3899156ec6ccfd02c58960e/pandas/io/json/_json.py#L123) and how the `mode` and `orient` parameters are handled there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be trying to do Haskell-style pattern-matching on the arguments. For example, the following is valid Haskell:

```
apply_indicator df "rsi" = 1
apply_indicator df "ichimoku" = 2
```

Then `apply_indicator something "rsi" == 1` and `apply_indicator somethign "ichimoku" == 2`.

Python does *not* support this kind of function definition. If you want one function, you need to do the matching *inside* the function, mostly simply with an `if` statement:

```
def apply_indicator(df, indicator):
    if indicator == "rsi":
        print("first one")
    elif indicator == "ichimoku":
        print("second one")
```

However, a function that does two different things based on explicit examination of one of its arguments is an anti-pattern. Your caller already has to decide what *argument* to pass to `apply_indicator`; they can just as easily decide which of two *functions* to call instead.

```
def apply_rsi(df):
    print("first one")

def apply_ichimoku(df):
    print("second one")
```

If you feel the need to "index" your set of parameter by a given argument, you can do that with a `dict` that maps the intended argument to the correct function:

```
d = {"rsi": apply_rsi, "ichimoku": apply_ichimoku}
x = ...  # rsi or ichimoku
d[x](some_df)
```